# Changing Directshow "virtual web-camera" from external application

Tags: c++, directshow

I have some DSLR-camera's that creates images. I created a DirectShow "Virtual Webcam" to output the images as a "webcam-device". I got this working using "vivek vcam". But there are still some issues. Currently I have this "this ugly setup".

```
Creation:
// each .dll has hardcoded DSLR-id
// each .dll used unique GIUD. for class derived from CSource
regsvr32 Virtcam1.dll
regsvr32 Virtcam2.dll
regsvr32 Virtcam3.dll

Usage:
DSLR 1 ---> VirtCam1 --> OBS-software 
DSLR 2 ---> VirtCam2 --> OBS-software
DSLR 3 ---> VirtCam3 --> OBS-software
```

I want to use more DSLR-camera's but building a DLL-file for every camera is stupid. Also when I add more camera's this way, OBS will keep them all active, consuming CPU and creating some other bottlenecks.

What I want to create is something like this:

```
               |-----------|
DSLR 1   --->  | VirtCam_x | --> OBS-software 
DSLR ... --->  | VirtCam_y | --> OBS-software
DSLR n   --->  | VirtCam_z | --> OBS-software
               |           |
               |-----------| <---> CameraManager.exe
```

I want to build a CameraManager.exe that alters the "Virtual DirectShow Webcams" while they are in use by OBS. (for for example throttling down framerates for camera's that are Idle).

**So my main question is this:**
How or where can I store data that is accessible from inside the "CStreamSource" and from the "CameraManager.exe"?

Maybe it's obvious, but I'm a big newbie to COM/Directshow. I also have no clue about windows registries. I got lost in the MSDN-pages. It would be nice to know what principles to use to make it work.

Thanks in advance for time and effort spend.